# How to show If else condition in a UML system sequence diagram

Tags: if-statement, sequence-diagram, uml

Is it possible to describe an if-else structure in a system sequence diagram? If yes, how is this done?

Comment: Here I've found a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114797/570339

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's more info about combined fragments from the VS 2010 sequence diagram documentation:

- [UML Sequence Diagrams: Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409377.aspx)
- [UML Sequence Diagrams: Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409389.aspx)
- [Describing Control Flow with Fragments in UML Sequence Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465153.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done in UML 2 using the 'Alternative' [combined fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram#Diagram_building_blocks) type, although personally I find them relatively difficult to read. There is a good example in [this IBM DeveloperWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This can be done in sequence diagrams. Not only if else,You can show loops, breaks and parallel etc.You have to learn [combined fragment](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) which is a sub-type of interaction fragment, to do that.