# How to show "if" condition on a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I was wondering, how can one represent "`if`" statement on a sequence diagram?

```
if (somethingShouldBeDone) {
       // Do it
} else {
       // Do something else
}
```

Can it be represented at all? The thing is ... in my code, fair amount of conditions are checked to determine a variety of actions. If i am going to show the actions, I'd like to explicitly state that actions are caused by particular events.

If possible create an image representation of a solution.

Comment: I know this question is old and I haven't done a search yet, but it made me wonder whether showing branching is even a good idea for sequence diagrams. I always thought the conditions for the sequence were explicitly described in the scenario and thus no branching took place during the sequence.  Alternative paths were handled by describing a variant of the scenario which had its own sequence diagram.  It's somewhat subjective so maybe I should post it on Meta or possibly Software Engineering?

Answer (score 403, accepted):

If else condition, also called alternatives in UML terms can indeed be represented in sequence diagrams. Here is a link where you can find some nice resources on the subject
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html

[image: branching with alt]

Comment: In Visio, is `Alt` called something else? I can't seem to find it

Comment: Visio in itself is not a UML modeling tool. If you want to use UML 2.0 then you need to find a good Visio Stencil that fully implements the 2.0 specifications. There are several free stencils available on the web, you might want to give some of them a try :) Here is one that looks good (did not try all the features though) http://softwarestencils.com/uml/

Comment: Are there any other UML tools apart from Visio. Is enterprise architect good enough?

Comment: @VenkatMadhav I can't really say. I've never used it to its full power but from the reading I found on google, it should be pretty good

Comment: @Venkat I'm personally a fan of visual paradigm. (http://www.visual-paradigm.com/)

Comment: In Astah this is called combinedFragment alt. Look for an icon between Stop and InteractionUse

Comment: @Jam There is an `Alternative fragment` in Visio 2013

Comment: [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)  and  [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings/) offer free UML drawing tools from what I can see.

Comment: Late and maybe not what everybody wants, but I just discovered the joys of plantuml (https://www.plantuml.com/). It's a UML markup language which can automatically be rendered as UML diagrams. Way faster and more maintable than drawing diagrams by hand. There is a free online editor if you want to try it. There is also an IntelliJ plugin which seamlessly renders the diagrams within a markdown document, and a GitHub action (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/generate-plantuml) which allows viewing it there too.

Answer (score 49):

If you paste

```
A.do() {
  if (condition1) {
   X.doSomething
  } else if (condition2) {
   Y.doSomethingElse
  } else {
   donotDoAnything
  }
}
```

onto https://app.zenuml.com. It will generate a diagram for you.[image: If/else sequence diagram]

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani have you tried the Chrome extension?

Comment: If it is `A.do(int condition)` -- If .. else ... else, can not all happen as a result of one call. Flow depends on the condition argument. It would be lovely if ZenUML could draw that. It would be three calls ordered in time.

Comment: @ChefGladiator I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you please add some pseudo code here? Or you can point me in the site.

Comment: Sure, here is the code : https://wandbox.org/permlink/PURdGJc8YxJmpUh7 -- there are three calls reuired for all the condition to be met. UML Sequence should show three calls, not one.

Comment: Of course, Activity diagrams are better to show algorithm internals/

Comment: I think not :) You need to have three calls coming from the left, each call is making the program flow inside F different. One call one activity.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7OL26FJ like this? SO should have a DM functionality :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195701/discussion-between-chef-gladiator-and-xiao-peng-zenuml-com).

Answer (score 27):

Very simple , using **Alt fragment**

Lets take an example of sequence diagram for an ATM machine.Let's say here you want

**IF** card inserted is valid then prompt "Enter Pin"....**ELSE** prompt "Invalid Pin"

Then here is the sequence diagram for the same

[image: ATM machine sequence diagram]

Hope this helps!

Comment: See [https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram), `Grouping message` section.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio UML sequence this can also be described as fragments which is nicely documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465153.aspx

Comment: Just as an heads up, the UML designer has been removed from VS 2017 onwards.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/modeling/what-s-new-for-design-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#uml-designers-have-been-removed

Comment: To clarify, UML is still in Visio - just not in Visual Studio. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uml-diagrams-in-visio-ca4e3ae9-d413-4c94-8a7a-38dac30cbed6