# Showing multiple booleans in sequence diagram

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

How to represent nesting of conditionals in sequence diagram? The image as given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164421/how-to-represent-an-if-condition1-else-if-contion2-on-a-sequence-diagram) depicts if/else:

[image]

How could I cater for the following:

```
if(a == 1 && b == 3) {

}else {


}
```

I need to represent multiple boolean conditions. I could not find anywhere that taught me to represent this.

Comment: Since my answer is the only one here - can you please think of selecting it as this question's answer, and possibly upvote it? Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here is quite simple:

Replace the value of the `[Success]` guard (as seen in diagram above) with `[a==1 && b==3]`

References:

- [How to show if condition on a sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114770/how-to-show-if-condition-on-a-sequence-diagram)
- [UML Sequence Diagram Tutorial](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/uml-sequence-diagram)