# How can I demonstrate switch-case statement in sequence diagram

Tags: switch-statement, sequence-diagram

I have seen switch-case recommendations for activity diagram, however I can not find an example for sequence diagram. Do we have to use `break` keyword while drawing or just drawing conditions only?

Comment: I will use conditions for this. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403292/529187

Comment: @XiaoPeng-ZenUML.com I also did similar but not sure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: use of switch case in sequence diagram]
I use the alternative block with more than one condition in them, see the pic above

I am not sure about the correctness of this but I use this way to use the switch case in the sequence diagram and it is posted at the link below:
http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/